# Android back arrow returns to home screen after focus loss

Tags: android, kotlin

I have run into a strange situation where if the back button is pressed, the user is sent to the previous activity.

However if the user goes to the home screen, or switches apps, then returns back to the app. Then presses the back button, instead of going to the previous activity, it returns back to the android home screen.

the activity is being started by:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);                                                                                                                                 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

as a note: the activity is being created by a library.
The flow works correctly when the integrating app is a java based application, and the incorrect flow comes up when it is integrating with a kotlin application.

Has anyone experienced anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` puts the launched `Activity` in a new task.  Returning to the app takes the user back into that task, which has only that `Activity` in it.  Thus, the back button drops the user back to the home screen.  This doesn't happen when the user hasn't gone home, because your app's previous task is immediately below the new task at that time.

You should start the `Activity` without that flag, which will probably require the app to pass an `Activity` to start it from to your library.

I think the Kotlin/Java distinction here is an unrelated coincidence.